# Conditions for integrals to be equal

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that $f, g,h:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions that satisfy $f,g\geq 0$ and  $$\int_0^1 f(t)h(t)dt = \int_{0}^1 g(t)h(t)dt.$$ What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $h$ to ensure that $$\int_0^1f(t)dt = \int_0^1g(t)dt?$$

EDIT: (**Some thoughts:**)
I thought maybe if $h>0$, this would be enough. However, I was shown that, for example, if $ f = 1/h $ and $g = 1/\left(\int h\right)$, then $$\int fh = \int gh.$$ In this case, for $\int f = \int g$ to be satisfied,  $h$ must satisfy $$\int \frac{1}{h} = \frac{1}{\int h}$$ and of course many $h>0$ do not satisfy that condition (e.g. $h(t) = 1+t$). Since, as user251257 points out, $h(t) \equiv1$ is sufficient, I was curious what the answer to the above might be.

(**Where this question came from**) I originally came across this question when looking at what can be said when you have solutions $y_i$ and $y_2$ to the Ricatti equations $y_i' + y^2_i + r_i =0$ on the interval $[a,b]$ that satisfy $y_1(a) = y_2(a)$ and $y_1(b) = y_2(b)$. In this case, you can write $$0 = g(y_2(t)-y_1(t))|_a^b = \int_a^b g(r_1(t)-r_2(t))dt$$ where $g$ is a function that satisfies $g' = (y_1 + y_2)g$. So, I wanted to claim that this means $\int_a^b r_1(t)dt = \int_a^b r_2(t)dt$, and in the process, I realized I didn't know the answer to the question above.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: $h(t) = 1$ looks pretty sufficient to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some a bit heuristic justification for why I don't expect anything more useful than $h$ being constant to work: think of the set of integrable functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space. Then what you're saying is that we have some element $f-g$ of that space such that $\langle f-g, h\rangle = 0$, i.e. $f-g\in h^\perp$ and you're asking for conditions on $h$ which would imply that $\langle f-g, 1\rangle = 0$, i.e. $f-g\in 1^\perp$. Now if $h$ and $1$ are not proportional to each other, there's no way for that implication to work.

Note that $f,g\geq 0$ doesn't change the generality of the above argument, since any element of our vector space can be written as a difference of nonnegative elements.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the very useful way to think about it.

Comment: I won't be such pessimistic, as $h=f-g$ is also sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will work except $h(x)=c$ constant.

Here's a sketch of the argument: suppose $h(a) \neq h(b)$ for $a,b\in (0,1)$. The you can pick $f$ to be a small bump near $x=a$ with height $1/h(a)$, and similarly for $g$ and $b$.

It may help to take a step back and build intuition in finite dimensions. If $v,w,h$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and $n>1$) and you have 
$$u\cdot h=v\cdot h,$$
there is no reason to believe that
$$u\cdot\mathbf{1} = v\cdot \mathbf{1},$$
and the situation doesn't change in infinite dimensions.

Comment: Right. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

**There has to be a constant $c\neq 0$ such that $h(x)=c$  for almost all $x\in [0,1]$.** Sufficiency is obvious, as is the necessity of $c\neq 0$. We prove the necessity of $h$ being essentially constant. In the following, let $I=[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ be Lebesgue measure. The argument works for every probability space though.

We first show that if there is no $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x)=c$ for almost all $x$, then there exists $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $U_k=\{x\in I:h(x)>k\}$ and $L_k=\{x\in I:h(x)<k\}$ both have positive measure. To see this, pick any $c\in\mathbb{R}$. If both $U_c$ and $L_c$ have positive measure, we are done, and if both have measure zero, then $h(x)=c$ for almost all $x\in I$. For the remaining cases, assume that $U_c$ does have positive measure and $L_c$ does not (the other case works essentially the same way.) Let $$s=\inf\Big\{w\in\mathbb{R}: \lambda\Big(h^{-1}\big((-\infty,w)\big)\Big)>0\Big\}.$$
The set over which the infimum is taken is clearly nonempty and bounded below by $c$, so the infimum exists. For any natural number $n$, we must have $\lambda\Big(h^{-1}\big((-\infty,s+1/n)\big)\Big)>0$. However, we must also have $\lambda\Big(h^{-1}\big((s+1/n^*,\infty)\big)\Big)>0$ for some $n^*$. Otherwise, we would have $h(x)=s$ for amost all $x\in I$. So we can take $k=s+1/n^*$.

So assume there is no $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x)=c$ for almost all $x\in I$. Pick some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that both $U_k$ and $L_k$ have positive measure. Let $\alpha_u=1/\lambda(U_k)\int_{U_k} h~\mathrm d\lambda$ and $\alpha_l=1/\lambda(L_k)\int_{L_k} h~\mathrm d\lambda$ and note that $\alpha_u>k>\alpha_l$. Indeed $\alpha_u$ is the average value of $h$ over $U_k$ and $\alpha_l$ is the average value of $h$ over $L_k$.

Assume for now that $\alpha_u\neq0\neq\alpha_l$.  Let $$f=1_{U_k} \frac{\alpha_l}{\alpha_u}\frac{\lambda(L_k)}{\lambda(U_k)}$$
and $g=1_{L_k}$. Then $$\int fh~\mathrm d\lambda=\alpha_l\lambda(L_k)=\int gh~\mathrm d\lambda,$$
but
$$\int f~\mathrm d\lambda=\frac{\alpha_l}{\alpha_u}\lambda(L_k)\neq 1\lambda(L_k)=\int g~\mathrm d\lambda.$$

It remains to dispose of the cases $\alpha_u=0$ and $\alpha_l=0$. We do the first, the second one can be dealt with in the same manner. If $\alpha_u=0$ then we can let $f=1_{U_k}$ and $g$ the constant function with value $0$. We then get
$$\int fh~\mathrm d\lambda=\alpha_u\lambda(U_k)=0=\int gh~\mathrm d\lambda,$$
but $$\int f~\mathrm d\lambda=\lambda(U_k)>0=\int g~\mathrm d\lambda.$$

**Edit:** The proof above does not take account of $f$ and $g$ having to be nonnegative. Indeed, it can happen that $\alpha_l<0<\alpha_u$, so that $\alpha_l/\alpha_u<0$ (that is the only thing that can go wrong). To take care of this case, let $f$ take the value $1$ on $U_k$ and the value $\frac{\alpha_u}{\alpha_l}\frac{\lambda(U_k)}{\lambda(L_k)}$ on $L_k$ and $0$ everywhere else. Also, let $g$ be the constant function with value zero. Then $\int fh=\int gh$, but $\int f>0=\int g$.